# Mudar style em div dinamicamente com input

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um `<input>` que queria adicionar uma função para alterar o tamanho do texto de um elemento `<h1>` sem precisar carregar a página pra isso ou clicar em um botão, apenas digitar e já ser alterado.

Minha ideia era digitar dentro do input e aplicar esse tamanho diretamente no style do elemento.

Por exemplo:

```
<input type="text">

<h1 style="font-size:(exibir o valor do input aqui)px;">Texto de exemplo</h1>
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) e [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Bom dia, Agusto Vasques, neste caso teria que "clicar" em lago pra gerar o que necessito...

Comment: Use um [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar algo parecido com isso:

```
<input id="sizeInput" type="number" />
<h1 id="text" fontsize="20">Texto de exemplo</h1>

<script>
    const sizeInput = document.getElementById('sizeInput');
    const text = document.getElementById('text');

    sizeInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

        text.style.fontSize = `${sizeInput.value}px`;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado Everton, exatamente isso que estava necessitando.

Comment: Posso adicionar outros input com diferentes configurações de estilização mesmo jquery. Como Por exemplo, se quiser adicionar um select par adicionar um Font-Weight: Bold;

Comment: O mecanismo seria parecido...
text.style.fontWeight = "bold"

Para saber mais:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar jquery para alterar de maneira o `font-size` do seu h1.

```
<input type='number' id='input'>
<h1 id='text'>Teste</p>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#input').on('input', function()
        {
            $('#text').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
        });
    });
</script>
```

A cada ação de input disparada ele irá alterar o `font-size`.

Comment: E em caso de um select pra usar um font-weight: Bold ou 900 por exemplo.

Comment: Você faz o mesmo, mas muda o $('#input').on('input'... para $('#id').on(change) e alterado .css('font-size'... para .css('font-weight', 'bold')

Leia: https://api.jquery.com/
Leia: https://api.jquery.com/css/

Essas são partes da documentação do jQuery que podem te ajudar muito. Se você não sabe como usa-lo, vale a pena estudar um pouco, facilita em relação ao JavaScript Vanilla.

Lembre-se que para dar certo o jquery acima você precisa importar o arquivo fonte dele no seu código. Um bom site sempre conta com jQuery.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, irei sim da uma olhadinha na documentação. Na verdade isso são exercícios que estou realizando para aprimoramento.  E que possa ajudar outras pessoas.